# extending a specific column header to include up/down arrows

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using MVC with the grid helper seen around.  I'm trying to extend a column header since I have to put up and down arrows for a certain column.  For example I call my header column sh and have the following using css to try to increase it but to no avail.  I'm wondering if anyone has a better idea.  I have heard of using javascript but I haven't used it before.

```
th.sh, td.sh
{
    width:50px;
    height:300px;
    border-top: 100px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: what serverside lang are you using? JSP, PHP, ASP, ??? or are you just applying sorting on the screen (e.g. not over paginated results)

Comment: I'm using client side now but asp server since using mvc.  It looks like no easy answer to this.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the specificity of your selector? (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity ). Another property may be overriding what you are trying to set with th.sh